# How can I make the b2 builder to default to -jN?

Tags: boost, build, buildconfiguration, parallel-builds, b2

I want to do boost builds in parallel by default, e.g. instead of `./b2 -j4` I want to just invoke `./b2` and have it use `-j4`, or `-jN` for some other relevant N, itself.

Can I do this? I was thinking maybe I could put in `tools/build/src/user-config.jam` somehow, but I'm not really well-versed enough in how that works.

Bonus points if I don't have to enter a value manually but have it determined by something like `nproc`, dynamically before building.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to just "pick it up" from the environment, but you can [put `option jobs : 4 ;` into any config file](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/3388)

Comment: @sehe: "any config file" - surely it must be some specific config file?

Comment: I'm just quoting that bit. I think it means what it says. Obviously, don't pick your win.ini (there are user, project and possibly more configs used by bjam)

Comment: @sehe: Fair enough; that's a half of an answer, I guess.